# RestClient::RequestTimeout in controller#method ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest-client

I am making the following rest get request:

```
 rest_user = JSON.parse(RestClient.get APP_CONFIG['api_url'] + "users/", :params => {:token => APP_CONFIG['token'], :full => 'true'} )["users"]
```

I get the following error back after a minute:

```
 RestClient::RequestTimeout in controller#method


rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:184:in `transmit'
rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:68:in `get'
```

Now when I am tailing the logs of the actual service that is receiving this request, it is performing the requested request and completes it without any error.

But the consumer(the web applicaion) is throwing the request timeout error before the request has actually been fully completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely normal. Your web app raises an error, because `RestClient` raises an error after 60 seconds if it has not received response yet.

The app you are calling has no knowledge of that fact, so it continues processing as long as it is required to complete the request (it may take, 61 seconds, 70, ... ).

```
url = APP_CONFIG['api_url'] + "users/"
payload = {:token => APP_CONFIG['token'], :full => 'true'}
RestClient::Execute.execute(method: :get, url: url, payload: payload, timeout: 120)
```

Comment: Is there a way around it. To increase the timeout from either side in the above code?

Comment: try `RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => url, :timeout => number_of_seconds )`

Comment: if I use execute I get a 403 forbidden for some reason

Comment: add params with token
`:params => {:token => APP_CONFIG['token'], :full => 'true'}`

Comment: Thanks. But if you look at my code, that's what I am doing. without the Request.execute I do not get the error.

Comment: `url = "#{APP_CONFIG['api_url']}users?token=#{APP_CONFIG['token']}&full=true"`

`RestClient::Execute.execute(method: :get, url: url, timeout: 120)`



Yes I understand, you have to call the request with proper timeout limit. you got 403, because token was not passed in params

Comment: @djaszczurowski Can I set timeout without using execute method ?